# Trigger con retardo

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Como hacer que un trigger cambie el valor de un registro después de un tiempo determinado?

Comment: `SELECT SLEEP(<seconds>);` por ejemplo

Comment: Perfecto gracias, lo podías haber puesto como respuesta!!